# What is the difference between a coefficient in an OLS regression model and the mean difference in a Tukey's HSD test?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I'm wondering if someone could explain in high-school-level language what the difference is between these concepts?

I'm looking at the results of an OLS regression for a single categorical variable (advertising budget: low, medium, high) against a target variable that represents sales ($).

The OLS results show the following:

|  | coef | 95% confidence interval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| intercept | 300 | 295.92 305.79 |
| low | -209 | -216.53 -203.2 |
| medium | -105 | -112.13 -98.86 |

Then I have the results of a Tukey's HSD test:

| group 1 | group 2 | mean diff | 95% confidence interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| high | low | -209 | -217.84 -201.89 |
| high | medium | -105 | -113.43 -97.56 |
| low | medium | 104 | 96.83 111.92 |

The coefficients from the OLS model are exactly identical to the mean differences from the Tukey's test. However, they both claim to have a 95% confidence in their given intervals, but the intervals are different.

1. Is there a theoretical difference between the coefficients in an OLS model and the mean differences in a Tukey's HSD test?
2. What is the difference between these two results?
3. How do I interpret that difference?
4. Is one way better than the other?

Thank you!